# Form Confirmation

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to pass data from a successful form submission to a thank you page that could then display this data. I am trying to do a reverse HttpResponseRedirect, but I keep getting this error:

NoReverseMatch at /contactform/process
Reverse for 'thankyou' with arguments '(24,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'contactform/thankyou/$']

Here is the code I have so far:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic


from .models import Contact_Object

def index(request):
    template_name = 'contactform/index.html'
    return render(request, 'contactform/index.html')

def thankyou(request, entered_id):
    contact_info = get_object_or_404(Contact_Object, pk=contact_object_id)
    template_name = 'contactform/thankyou.html'
    return render(request, 'contactform/thankyou.html', {name: contact_info.name})

def process(request):
        entered_name = request.POST['fullname']
        entered_email = request.POST['email']
        entered_message = request.POST['message']
        entered = Contact_Object(name=entered_name, email=entered_email, message=entered_message)
        entered.save()
        entered_id = entered.id
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contactform:thankyou', args=(entered.id,)))
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'contactform'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^thankyou/$', views.thankyou, name='thankyou'),
    url(r'^process$', views.process, name='process'),
]
```

**Template for Form**

```
<H1>Contact Form</H1>


<FORM action="{% url 'contactform:process' %}" method="post"> 
{% csrf_token %}
    Full Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="fullname"><br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" ><br>
    Message:<br>
    <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Enter"> 
</FORM>
```

**Template for Thank you page**

```
<h1>Thank You</h1>
<p>Thank you, {% contact_info.name %}</p>
```

I'm new to working with Python/Django so I feel it's probably an obvious beginners mistake, I just can't seem to spot it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is right here:

```
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contactform:thankyou', args=(entered.id,)))
```

the `thankyou` url doesn't take any arguments.

```
url(r'^thankyou/$', views.thankyou, name='thankyou'),
```

To fix it you should change it to this:

```
url(r'^thankyou/([0-9]*)$', views.thankyou, name='thankyou'),
```

Using the `reverse` function and the `args` kwarg, it translates it into a usable URL like: `/thankyou/24` plugging in the args provided in the `args` iterable. You can also use `kwargs` to pass in keywords to your url if you're using keyword groupings in your url as described below.

See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#example

Each of the regex groupings is an argument that gets passed to the view.

You can also have keyword arguments passed if you do the url like this:

```
url(r'^thankyou/(?P<pk>[0-9]*)$', views.thankyou, name='thankyou'),
```

and in a function based view you would access it by defining it in the view function signature like this:

```
def thankyou(request, pk=None):
```